# Magento 2: How to create new Checkout Step and put the redirection?

Tags: magento2, checkout, steps

I need to add a new Checkout step and when I click on that step it should be redirected to the view cart page. I have created a new step already and below is my js code. How can make the redirection over the step.

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        Component,
        _,
        stepNavigator,
        customer
    ) {
        'use strict';
        /**
        * check-login - is the name of the component's .html template
        */
        return Component.extend({


            //add here your logic to display step,
            isVisible: ko.observable(true),
            isLogedIn: customer.isLoggedIn(),
            //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
            stepCode: 'mycart',
            //step title value
            stepTitle: 'My cart',

            /**
            *
            * @returns {*}
            */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                // register your step
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    this.stepCode,
                    //step alias
                    null,
                    this.stepTitle,
                    //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                    this.isVisible,

                    _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                    /**
                    * sort order value
                    * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                    * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                    * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                    */
                    7
                );

                return this;
            },

            /**
            * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
            * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
            * for switching to your custom step
            */
            navigate: function () {
                
            },

            /**
            * @returns void
            */
            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                stepNavigator.navigateTo('payment');
            }
        });
    }
);
```

[image]

Please guide

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for better understanding?

Comment: @SohelRana, I have added the screenshot, you can see I have created a new step called My Cart, now when customer clicks the step, its should be redirected to the cart page. How can I give hyper link as this my cart page dont have any content and we are showing this as a static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator': {
                'SR_MagentoCommunity/js/mixin/navigator-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/web/js/mixin/navigator-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'mage/url'
], function ($, ko, wrapper, urlBuilder) {
    'use strict';

    return function (stepNavigator) {
        stepNavigator.navigateTo = wrapper.wrap(stepNavigator.navigateTo, function (originalAction, code, scrollToElementId) {
            if (code == 'custom_step') {
                var url = urlBuilder.build('checkout/cart/index');
                window.location.href = url;
            }
            return originalAction(code, scrollToElementId);
        });

        return stepNavigator;
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check and get back

Comment: Great its working, now the redirection happens when I click on the step. Can you tell me how can I show the active step from second step (Shipping) instead of first step which is my custom step?

Comment: My custom step is jumping/changing the position when refreshing the page. What could be the issue? please guide

Comment: Hey, that shouldn't be. Can you share your code?

Comment: I have attached my code. As per your answer, now the redirection is working perfectly. My requirement is just show the My cart step before the shipping step and the new step doesn't have any template. How can I make this step inactive but show before the shipping. Please help